# Store File in S3 from a Lambda Function using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I've been trying to figure out how to take an Event from DynamoDB and then store that event as a json file in S3.  I am able to consume the event from DynamoDB just fine; however, I am unable to then create and store the file in S3.

I get the following error in CloudWatch from the Lambda Function:

> Error Message: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: {Keys: {Id={S: 301,}},NewImage: {Total={S: 99999,}, Event={S: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO,}, Id={S: 301,}, Name={S: 7777777777777777777,}},OldImage: {Total={S: 99999,}, Event={S: ------------------,}, Id={S: 301,}, Name={S: ------------------,}},SequenceNumber: 6500000000000355579183,SizeBytes: 126,StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES} (File name too long)

Here's my Lambda Java Handler:

```
    import java.io.File;

    import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
    import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
    import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent.DynamodbStreamRecord;
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

    public class StreamsLambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<DynamodbEvent, Object> {

         public String handleRequest(DynamodbEvent ddbEvent, Context context) {
             LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

             for (DynamodbStreamRecord record : ddbEvent.getRecords()){
                 logger.log("-----EVENT ID: " + record.getEventID() + "\n");
                 logger.log("-----EVENT NAME: " + record.getEventName() + "\n");
                 logger.log("-----RECORD:  " + record.getDynamodb().toString() + "\n");

                saveToS3(record.getDynamodb().toString(), "NewlyCreatedFile.json", logger);
             }



             return "Successfully processed " + ddbEvent.getRecords().size() + "records.";

         }

         private void saveToS3 (String jsonDocument, String keyName, LambdaLogger logger) {

            final String bucketName     = "com.spinaction.events";
            AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());

                try {
                    System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
                    File file = new File(jsonDocument);
                    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                                             bucketName, keyName, file));

                 } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
                    logger.log("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
                            "means your request made it " +
                            "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
                            " for some reason.");
                    logger.log("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
                    logger.log("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
                    logger.log("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
                    logger.log("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
                    logger.log("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
                } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                    logger.log("Caught an AmazonClientException, which " +
                            "means the client encountered " +
                            "an internal error while trying to " +
                            "communicate with S3, " +
                            "such as not being able to access the network.");
                    logger.log("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
                    logger.log(ace.getStackTrace().toString());
                }
         }
    }
```

Here is the functioning code, once modified to leverage InputStream instead of File.  In addition, need to ensure your Lambda executing this code has the appropriate permissions to S3.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent.DynamodbStreamRecord;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.StorageClass;

public class StreamsLambdaFunctionHandler implements
    RequestHandler<DynamodbEvent, Object> {

public String handleRequest(DynamodbEvent ddbEvent, Context context) {
    LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

    for (DynamodbStreamRecord record : ddbEvent.getRecords()) {
        logger.log("-----EVENT ID: " + record.getEventID() + "\n");
        logger.log("-----EVENT NAME: " + record.getEventName() + "\n");
        logger.log("-----RECORD:  " + record.getDynamodb().toString()
                + "\n");

        saveToS3(record.getDynamodb().toString(), "NewlyCreatedFile.json",
                logger);
    }

    return "Successfully processed " + ddbEvent.getRecords().size()
            + "records.";

}

private void saveToS3(String jsonDocument, String keyName,
        LambdaLogger logger) {

    final String bucketName = "com.spinaction.events";
    AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(
            new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());

    try {
        System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                jsonDocument.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String bucket = bucketName;
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType("application/json");
        metadata.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename=\"" + keyName);
        PutObjectRequest put = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, keyName,
                stream, metadata);
        put.setStorageClass(StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy);
        put.setMetadata(metadata);
        s3client.putObject(put);

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        logger.log("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which "
                + "means your request made it "
                + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response"
                + " for some reason.");
        logger.log("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        logger.log("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        logger.log("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        logger.log("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        logger.log("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        logger.log("Caught an AmazonClientException, which "
                + "means the client encountered "
                + "an internal error while trying to "
                + "communicate with S3, "
                + "such as not being able to access the network.");
        logger.log("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Given the error `(File name too long)`... do you see the bug in this line? `File file = new File(jsonDocument);`

Comment: Solved the problem.  Due to my own ignorance.  java.io.File is a reference to a file.  When consuming an event from DBDynamo, there is no file reference, therefore you need to create an inputstream and stream the bytes out to S3.